# When I run the app I get an bind or index column out of range SQL exception

Tags: android

DbAdapter function:

```
public boolean test(String username, String password){
        boolean x;
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM Login WHERE Customer_Name='?' AND Password='?'", new String[] {username, password});
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
          x=true;
        } else {
          x=false;
        }
    return x;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove single quotes around `?` and it will work fine.

Correct code should be

```
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM Login WHERE Customer_Name=? AND Password=?", new String[] {username, password});
```

Comment: But the authentication is not checked. It always returns true.

Comment: the sql query seems fine. Check the values of username and password that are passed into function. Also, try using query instead of rawQuery method.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide more code, where you show the creation of the table. As far as I see the above code looks fine. Could be a Variable that does not match.

Comment: private static final String DATABASE_CREATE0 = "create table Login (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "+ "Customer_Name text not null, Password text not null);";

Answer (score 0):

Error many be Customer_Name or Password are not column in  the table Login.

Answer (score 0):

As well as checking the column names exist:

1. Have you tried it with username and password values that definitely exist? And not null?
2. Have you tried it without the single quotes around the question marks?

Comment: I pass the values with the help of DBHelper object like boolean x = DBHelper.test(UNAME, UPASS); These Values I gather from the Editboxes in my UI.